# Semaphores: Where do I learn about basic concepts such as permits, fairness, barging, etc

Tags: java, android, semaphore

The **Semaphore** class overview in [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) looks pretty good - for those who are already familiar with the concepts and terminology.

I am familiar with some of the acronyms and other jargon there (e.g. FIFO, lock, etc.) but others such as `permits`, `fairness` and `barging` are new to me.

Can you recommend a good online source for explaining these concepts? (I can probably figure out what *permits* and *fairness* are but `barging` is an unknown at this point).

EDIT: After receiving the two answers below, I realized that I need a refresh on semaphores (to re-acquire() terminology). I found the following resources to be useful:

1. [Semaphore_(programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29)
2. [Introduction to Semaphores](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/150CCP/lectures/Lecture10.pdf) by
   Dr. Richard S. Hall

Answer (score 1):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

This is an excerpt from what is considered one of the seminal works in java concurrency you should check it out.
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/0321349601/explicit-locks/287

Answer (score 1):

Hadn't come across these myself, but thought I'd research and summarise my findings as it's better to in-line answers than link externally (although, yes, the OP is after recommending reading):

**permits** are the number of concurrent accesses allowed to the semaphore-protected code. Although often semaphores are simple Mutex's, it is sometimes desirable to have more than one thread touching code. This is similar to phoning a call-centre, where there's one phone number connected to 8 lines/operators.

**fairness** is when a semaphore is made available to requesters in strict order of who requested first. Staying with the call-centre analogy, this means the on-hold queue is a strict FIFO.

**barging** is essentially an out-of-band request, that puts a thread to the top of the queue for a semaphore. The analogy is where preferred customers (or internal calls) go to the top of a call-centre queue, rather than waiting their turn.

If neither **fairness** nor **barging** are specified, then it's within spec to grant access to the most recent request, depending on timing of context switches. The 'phone analogy is a call to a company switchboard/reception, where even if calls are on hold waiting for answer, you may get lucky and ring between one call ending and another call being taken off-hold.

Let me know through comments if I've got this wrong, and I'll fix / cw my answer.